# ios : Assertion failure UITableView dataSource is not set

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why I am getting an error like this? In my appicaction I am loading webview inside a table view.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6048
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource is not set'
```

Comment: Have you set dataSource property of your tableView?

Comment: Yes and it is loading, but when I am scrolling to bottom of the tableview it is crashing.

Comment: The number of rows, did you remember to do -1 on it ?

Comment: how did you fix this issue finally?

Comment: Can we see the code for your table view delegate / data source  methods?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was a DatePicker throwing the error when I set it's .date property in viewDidLoad. When I moved the code to viewDidAppear, the issue gone.

This error happen only in iPhone 4s, not other later models, iPhone nor iPad.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old issue, I know, but I ran into the same issue in iOS 11.0 and Swift 4.0.

I have a `UITableViewController` and I had added the `tableView` from this as a `subview` to another view. Every time I debugged the `tableView` the `viewDidLoad` was called correctly and it printed out the right values. The error occurred when the `cellForRowAt` ran the second time.

The solution for me was to add the whole `UITableViewController` as a `addChildViewController` to the parent view where I wanted the `tableView` to appear.

I know this probably don't help the *OP* today but there might be someone out there struggeling with an issue like this today.

Comment: I'm adding a tableview to a collectionview cell. It doesn't allow 'addChildViewController' to be called so I only set the subview. Any ideas on how to do what you're talking about for a collectionview cell?

Answer (score 0):

I was also encountering this issue. (Spent days to identify it.) Just now, I've solved it. I am not a hundred percent sure what has solved the problem but what I changed was to populate all my views(some custom configurations) in the viewDidLoad, instead of viewWillAppear.

Somehow something was causing a dataSource problem. I just want to suggest anyone: whatever you're doing in viewWillAppear that might be related to tableView, try it in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your `UITableView`'s data source is not set :)

More helpfully, have you checked that in your xib you have connected up the dataSource property from your tableview?